# Webpage that does not scroll left or right

Tags: html, css

The following webpage does not allow the user to scroll left or right. This is an issue when the viewport is smaller than 960px as the site is not responsive.

The site doesn't scroll when javascript is disabled which leads me to believe that this is being achieved by HTML or CSS

What code is achieving this and how do I remove it?

Site: http://oddschanger.com

Comment: what browser and version you test i `use ff 19.0.2` and scroll bar work when screen smaller than 960px

Answer (score 2):

there's a lovely

```
overflow-x: hidden
```

in main.css line 166

hope this help

Comment: To clear this up in case the OP didn't understand, the `overflow-x: hidden`, I think, should be removed.